# How to display full website in Unity WebGL?

Tags: unity, c#, webgl, .net

I want to display the complete website within the WebGL in Unity. I have tried Awesomium plugin but it doesn't work in WebGL. Please tell me is there any way to display the webpage.

Thank you.

Comment: You mention you're using WebGL. If you're already running in a web-based context, why not just use the browser itself? This will likely have better performance and fewer quirks than emulating a browser-in-a-game-in-another-browser. If you need cross-communication between the browser rendering the webpage and the Unity game, that can be accomplished by other means without literally hosting the web page inside of the Unity game.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no plugin that renders a website and supports WebGL.

I conclude two things from this. **A**, you have to do it yourself, get ready to research website rendering, suitable libraries for Mono maybe and probably a lot more.

And **B**, it won't be easy or even possible to do it (with acceptable performance). Rendering webpages is a feature many people want but plugins doing that mostly only support one platform (only windows or only android, etc.).

Comment: Yes, i didn't find any plugins to do it. So now i'm planning to use just API's for specific actions.